# How to show UIToolbar in the UIView

Tags: iphone, ios4

MainViewController have `UIToolbar` and when button is pressed on the `UIToolbar`, it displays view i want to show the `UIToolbar` in all my views.

I set this command in display view action

```
 [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:NO];
```

but this statement is not helping in displaying `UIToolbar` in the view

```
- (void)displayviewsAction:(id)sender
{

   self.view = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]]autorelease];

  [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

 PageOneViewController *viewController = [[[PageOneViewController alloc] init]autorelease];

[self.view addSubview:viewController.view];

[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:NO];

}
```

Please suggest how to show `UIToolbar` in views.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added

```
 [self.view addSubview:toolbar];
```

This helped in solving the issue.